# ASP.NET - Acessar atributo de item de DropDownList no Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownlist

Eu tenho um `DropDownList` no qual adiciono itens conforme abaixo:

```
var item= new ListItem("Texto do Item", "Valor do Item");
item.Attributes.Add("NomeAtributo", "ValorAtributo");
```

O `DropDownList` é renderizado na tela com o atributo, até ai legal. Quando seleciono um item no `DropDownList` dispara um evento no `code behind`, onde eu quero pegar de novo o valor do atributo, no entanto quando eu executo o código abaixo vem `null`:

```
var meuAtributo = meuDropDownList.SelectedItem.Attributes["NomeAtributo"];
```

Na documentação da ***Microsoft*** está escrito na descrição do `WebControl.Attributes`:

> `Gets the collection of arbitrary attributes (for rendering only)`

---

***Tradução:***

> `Pega a coleção de atributos arbitrários (somente para renderização).`

Como que eu faço para pegar o valor do atributo desse `DropDownList` no evento `OnSelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: é WebForms? tem o código completo disso?

Comment: SIm, é webforms, mas o código completo eu não posso postar, malz ai...tem alguma coisa que ficou obscura?

Comment: você usa o valores só no server-side ou em client-side também? É uma informação sómente na programação?

Comment: no evento OnLoad (server-side) eu crio o ddl com os valores e atributos. No evento OnSelectedIndexChanged (server-side) eu quero recuperar o atributo do item do ddl. Então eu crio e uso só no server-side. A única coisa que acontece no front-end é aparecer o atributo nas options do select renderizado, mas não tem nenhuma alteração ou processamento nem nada.

Comment: é o seguinte, dessa forma não tem como, `Attributes` só são mesmo para reenderizar, o que pode ser feito guardar os valores em um `ViewState` da própria página. Pergunto para cada item são muitos configurações?

Comment: É um atributo para cada item da lista, carregando do banco as informações e fazendo um loop vai ficar bom...valeu pela solução!!! Vou testar!

Comment: Você utilizou a resposta?

Comment: Obrigado @Virgilio, na correria acabei usando uma solução não tão elegante, mas foi muito útil em outra situação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente os atributos só server para renderizar a pagina, na recuperação da informação esses atributos são perdidos, mas, existe formas de contornar isso, uma seria gravar as informações no [ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Exemplo minimo:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) Load_Drop();
    }

    protected void Load_Drop()
    {
        var l1 = new ListItem("v1", "1");
        l1.Attributes.Add("a1", "r1");
        ViewState.Add("v1", "a1;r1");

        var l2 = new ListItem("v2", "2");
        l2.Attributes.Add("a2", "r2");
        ViewState.Add("v2", "a2;r2");

        DropDownList1.Items.Add(l1);
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(l2);            
        DropDownList1.DataBind();    

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var drop = DropDownList1;
        int index = drop.SelectedIndex;
        if (index > -1)
        {
            ListItem item = drop.SelectedItem;
            string values = (string)ViewState[item.Text];                    
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Referencias</sub>

- [Understanding ASP.NET View State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)
- [Saving Web Forms Page Values Using View State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yfdwycw(v=vs.71).aspx)